# What type of Resistors be used with Triac terminals? 1/4 or 1 watt

Tags: resistors, switches, ac, triac

I have used BTA41-600 with MOC3083. I Keep frying my MT1/2 connected 330E and 360E resistors. Resistors were used as per datasheet recommendation. I was using 330E and 360E but, both kept frying. 240V ac load of 100W (incandescent bulb) was connected exactly as per datasheet recommendation. Circuit is shown below.[image]

Capacitor is MPC Triac fires "OK"(thanks to [ANDY aka](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/20218/andy-aka)), but as soon as it fires it blows the resistors as told. Help needed.

Comment: Just calculate the power dissipation and add some safety margin.

Comment: please elaborate on this. Power dissipation at resistor? How to do that with a 2 port device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as the opto-triac turns on it should trigger the power triac and the dissipation in the resistors should drop to about nothing. 1/4-W is fine.

If the resistors are 'frying' it's a good indication that your power triac is connected incorrectly, missing entirely or faulty.

Comment: But the triac is new and i switched it first time when it fried. Connections are all ok. I checked them multiple times.

Comment: Did you mean the current is passing through phototriac instead of power triac? How to check if triac is triggered properly or not? and above all suggest a resistor which can withstand such dissipation. Is it possible that because of low load it fried? I connected only 100W incandescent bulb. Nohting else.

Comment: If you want the resistors to survive a defective or incorrectly connected triac, use 50W resistors for each.

Comment: I am having "giggles:; its not funny. I asked how to check that and some value of resistor or any other method to stop this from happening.

Comment: Try connecting just a resistor (say 15K 5 Watt) between MT2 and gate. Nothing else but the incandescent bulb load. If the lamp switches on (perhaps not quite full brightness) the triac is working.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the resistor to 1watt and it worked. the reason it worked was because the power dissipation of opto triac was .5W so resistors must have been at minimum that also the gate connection was loose.